# Return a two array confusion matrix

Tags: java, methods, return

I'm trying to create a confusion matrix however I'm not sure how to properly return my method where I can index both predicted and actual values, here's what I have tried thus far:

```
    int[][] matrixConfusion(int[] predicted, int[] actual){
        
        int[] count = new int [10];
        int counts = 0;
        int counts1 = 0;
        int counts2 = 0;
        int counts3 = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
        if(actual[i] == count[i] && predicted[i] == count[i]) {
            counts++;   
        }else if(actual[i] != count[i] && predicted[i] != count[i]) {
            counts1++;
        }else if(actual[i] != count[i] && predicted[i] == count[i]) {
            counts2++;
        }else if(actual[i] == count[i] && predicted[i] != count[i]) {
            counts3++;
        }
        
        }
        System.out.println("\t"+ "Actual = 0:"+"\t"+"Actual = 1:"+"\n" + "Predic = 0:" + "\t" + counts + "\t" + counts2 + "\n" + "Predic = 1:" + "\t" + counts3 + "\t" + counts1);
        return null;
        }
```

The code works by printing out the statements above however, I cannot find a way to properly return the values from print,so that I can return the values rather than print them.

Comment: `return new int[][] { new int[] {1, 1}, new int[] {counts, counts2}, new int[] {counts3, counts1} };` ?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis Thank you for that comment! I did not know that you could create arrays in that way in the return statement.